# How to draw a table with middle is empty

Tags: tables, tabularx

I want to draw a table as below:

[image]

I am struggling how to make the middle a blank space.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}



\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{lcclcc}
     \toprule
     \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Dataset}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Dataset2}}\\\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-3}
     & \thead{Number}
     & \thead{Values}\\
     \midrule

     \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use `\sisetup`  in your table since you have no `S`  column?

Comment: @Bernard, I just modify from my others table, very confusing.

Comment: But will you have `S` columns? Further, your table preamble uses 6 columns but your image show 4!

Comment: @Bernard. I edited my code.

Comment: Not a complete answer but I often use an empty column with `p{1cm}` type. The 1cm could be ajusted to your need.

Comment: @AlainRemillard, can you show me how it generate?

Comment: See the answer by @Bernard, this is what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\centering
%% select suitable overall width (e.g., 0.8\textwidth) and column width (e.g., 1.5cm)
\begin{tabular*}{0.8\textwidth}{ @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{4}{p{1.5cm}} }
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Dataset 1} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Dataset 2}\\
\cmidrule{1-2} \cmidrule{3-4}
Number & Values & Number & Values \\
\cmidrule{1-2} \cmidrule{3-4}
1 & 5 \\
2 & 4 \\
3 & 4 & 3 & 3.4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to make the content, (like decimal point) to be symmetric? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525926/i-want-my-decimal-be-justified-to-right-as-i-am-using-begintabular0-8-textw

Comment: @aan - Please see the answer I posted for your follow-up question.

Comment: thanks. both anwers in this question are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Is it something like this you want?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf},
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering\sffamily
 \begin{tabular}{llp{1em}ll}
     \toprule
     \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Dataset1}} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Dataset2}}\\
     \cmidrule{1-2}\cmidrule{4-5}
      \thead{Number} & \thead{Values} & & \thead{Number} & \thead{Values} \\
     \cmidrule[\lightrulewidth]{1-2}\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth]{4-5}
3 & 4 & &3 & 3.4 \\
     \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: both answers in this question is correct.