# I want numbers to be aligned on their decimal markers in a four-column table with two numeric columns

Tags: tables

This is following up question from [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525912/how-to-draw-a-table-with-middle-is-empty?noredirect=1#comment1330268_525912)

[image]

the decimal point make it symmetric in a line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\centering
%% select suitable overall width (e.g., 0.8\textwidth) and column width (e.g., 1.5cm)
\begin{tabular*}{0.8\textwidth}{ @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{4}{p{1.9cm}} }
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Dataset 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Dataset 2}}\\
\cmidrule{1-2} \cmidrule{3-4}
\textbf{Sample} & \textbf{Value} & \textbf{Sample} & \textbf{Value} \\
\cmidrule{1-2} \cmidrule{3-4}

1 & 10.1007 \\
2 & 9.620371 & 827.918 & 9.23345 \\
3 & 8.882499 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `p` columns are `\parbox` designed for text with linebreaking in the cells. you do not want that here use single line column such as `l` for the first column and a decimal alignment column (`D` from `dcolumn` package or `S` from `siunitix` for numeric columns)

Answer (score 5):

Since you load the `siunitx` package anyway, I'd use the `S` column type for columns 2 and 4.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=left,group-digits=false}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{0.8\textwidth}{ @{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
  p{2cm} S[table-format=2.6] p{2cm} S[table-format=1.5] }
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Dataset 1}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Dataset 2}} \\
\cmidrule{1-2} \cmidrule{3-4}
\textbf{Sample} & {\textbf{Value}} & 
\textbf{Sample} & {\textbf{Value}} \\
\cmidrule{1-2} \cmidrule{3-4}
1 & 10.1007 \\
2 & 9.620371 & 827.918 & 9.23345 \\
3 & 8.882499 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. I get very confused with this `\begin{tabular*}{0.8\textwidth}{ @{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
  p{2cm} S[table-format=2.6] p{2cm} S[table-format=1.5] }`. can you explain in simple english for this?

Comment: @aan - The `tabular*` environment takes 2 arguments. The 1st is the overall width, and the 2nd is akin to the single argument of a regular, i.e., non-starred, `tabular` environment. The `@{\extracolsep{\fill}} directive instructs LaTeX to increase the whitespace padding between columns in order to achieve the desired overall width. I trust you know what `p{2cm}` does. `S[table-format=2.6]` tells LaTeX to set aside enough space to typeset numbers with up to 2 integer digits and up to 6 decimal digits; `S[table-format=1.5]` is for numbers with 1 integer digits and up to 5 decimal digits.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use `siunitx` features.

I'd not widen the table, unless it is already almost as wide as the overall text width.

Bottom is how I'd realize the table. Only the necessary packages have been kept in the code.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row

\usepackage[
  font=small,
  labelfont={bf,sf},
  textfont={sf}, 
  justification=centering
]{caption}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!htp]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{group-digits=false}
\centering

\caption{The caption to the table}

%% select suitable overall width (e.g., 0.8\textwidth) and column width (e.g., 1.5cm)
\begin{tabular*}{0.8\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  c
  S[table-format=2.6]
  S[table-format=3.3]
  S[table-format=1.5]
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Dataset 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Dataset 2}}\\
\cmidrule{1-2} \cmidrule{3-4}
\textbf{Sample} & \textbf{Value} & \textbf{Sample} & \textbf{Value} \\
\cmidrule{1-2} \cmidrule{3-4}

1 & 10.1007 \\
2 & 9.620371 & 827.918 & 9.23345 \\
3 & 8.882499 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\sisetup{group-digits=false}
\centering

\caption{The caption to the table}

%% select suitable overall width (e.g., 0.8\textwidth) and column width (e.g., 1.5cm)
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  c
  S[table-format=2.6]
  S[table-format=3.3]
  S[table-format=1.5]
  @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{\textbf{Dataset 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\textbf{Dataset 2}}\\
\cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-4}
\textbf{Sample} & \textbf{Value} & \textbf{Sample} & \textbf{Value} \\
\midrule

1 & 10.1007 \\
2 & 9.620371 & 827.918 & 9.23345 \\
3 & 8.882499 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is not the optimal solution, but works fine for small tables. Try adding a `\phantom` space, for example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\centering
%% select suitable overall width (e.g., 0.8\textwidth) and column width (e.g., 1.5cm)
\begin{tabular*}{0.8\textwidth}{ @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{4}{p{1.9cm}} }
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Dataset 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Dataset 2}}\\
\cmidrule{1-2} \cmidrule{3-4}
\textbf{Sample} & \textbf{Value} & \textbf{Sample} & \textbf{Value} \\
\cmidrule{1-2} \cmidrule{3-4}

1 & 10.1007 \\
2 & \phantom{1}9.620371 & 827.918 & 9.23345 \\
3 & \phantom{1}8.882499 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Gives the table with the second column aligned as you want:
[image]